# R error in for loop: unexpected '=' and not recognising 'i'

Tags: r

I have this loop, where X is a tibble with 6 columns and 3000 rows:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(X)){if(X[i,6] = -999){
    X[i,6] <- NA
  }
}
```

When I wrote the code, it was running perfectly, substituting all the -999 cells with NA.
However now it is returning this error:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "for(i in 1:nrow(daily_Geul)){if(daily_Geul[i,6] ="
```

and

```
Error in `[<-.tbl_df`(`*tmp*`, i, 6, value = NA) : object 'i' not found
```

I have also tried using '==' instead of '=', but I get the same error back. As for the second error, I am confused as i should be defined by the for loop.
I don't know how to correct these, as until yesterday the loop was working fine.

Thank you in advance for your help, as sorry if the issue is basic :)

Comment: It should be `==` and not `=`

Comment: There are better ways to recode values (i.e. not using for loops). Try using the ifelse function instead.

Comment: The code works if you change `==` to `=`. Are you sure `daily_Geul` exists? As others have implied, you could also shorten this substantially to something like `X[,6][X[,6] == -999] <- NA`

Comment: in your `if statement` `if(X[i,6] = -999` I believe your **intent** is to compare so it should be `==`. A single `=` means you are assigning the value `-999` to each condition `X[i,6]` but I believe you want to check *if* `X[i,6]` equals `-999` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

assuming `X` is your `DataFrame` and that your datatype in `X[i,6]` is not `Character`

```
for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
    if(X[i,6] == -999){
    X[i,6] = NA
  }
}
```

Comment: As @thelatemail indicated, this could be shortened to just `X[,6][X[,6] == -999] <- NA`  to take advantage of R's vectorization.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you to everyone :)